# Read file character-by-character in Rust

Tags: io, rust

Is there an idiomatic way to process a file one character at a time in Rust?

This seems to be roughly what I'm after:

```
let mut f = io::BufReader::new(try!(fs::File::open("input.txt")));

for c in f.chars() {
    println!("Character: {}", c.unwrap());
}
```

But [`Read::chars`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/trait.Read.html#method.chars) is still unstable as of Rust v1.6.0.

I considered using [`Read::read_to_string`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/trait.Read.html#method.read_to_string), but the file may be large and I don't want to read it all into memory.

Comment: For some types of text files: `f.lines().flat_map(|l| l.chars())` ... but this is not really a good solution.

Comment: Have you considered just copying the implementation in the meantime? It's only ~100 lines and means your code will be trivial to upgrade if `chars`  stabilizes as-is.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Let's compare 4 approaches.

**1. `Read::chars`**

You could copy [`Read::chars`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/io/trait.Read.html#method.chars) implementation, but it is marked unstable with

> the semantics of a partial read/write of where errors happen is currently unclear and may change

so some care must be taken. Anyway, this seems to be the best approach.

**2. `flat_map`**

The `flat_map` alternative does not compile:

```
use std::io::{BufRead, BufReader};
use std::fs::File;

pub fn main() {
    let mut f = BufReader::new(File::open("input.txt").expect("open failed"));

    for c in f.lines().flat_map(|l| l.expect("lines failed").chars()) {
        println!("Character: {}", c);
    }
}
```

The problems is that `chars` borrows from the string, but `l.expect("lines failed")` lives only inside the closure, so compiler gives the error `borrowed value does not live long enough`.

**3. Nested for**

This code

```
use std::io::{BufRead, BufReader};
use std::fs::File;

pub fn main() {
    let mut f = BufReader::new(File::open("input.txt").expect("open failed"));

    for line in f.lines() {
        for c in line.expect("lines failed").chars() {
            println!("Character: {}", c);
        }
    }
}
```

works, but it keeps allocation a string for each line. Besides, if there is no line break on the input file, the whole file would be load to the memory.

**4. `BufRead::read_until`**

A memory efficient alternative to approach 3 is to use `Read::read_until`, and use a single string to read each line:

```
use std::io::{BufRead, BufReader};
use std::fs::File;

pub fn main() {
    let mut f = BufReader::new(File::open("input.txt").expect("open failed"));

    let mut buf = Vec::<u8>::new();
    while f.read_until(b'\n', &mut buf).expect("read_until failed") != 0 {
        // this moves the ownership of the read data to s
        // there is no allocation
        let s = String::from_utf8(buf).expect("from_utf8 failed");
        for c in s.chars() {
            println!("Character: {}", c);
        }
        // this returns the ownership of the read data to buf
        // there is no allocation
        buf = s.into_bytes();
        buf.clear();
    }
}
```

Comment: Where can I find the old Read::chars() implementation?

Comment: For now I've settled on this crate: https://crates.io/crates/utf8-chars

Answer (score 3):

I cannot use `lines()` because my file could be a single line that is gigabytes in size. This an improvement on [@malbarbo's recommendation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37189758/155423) of copying  `Read::chars` from the an old version of Rust. The [utf8-chars crate](https://crates.io/crates/utf8-chars) already adds `.chars()` to `BufRead` for you.

Inspecting their [repository](https://github.com/A1-Triard/utf8-chars/blob/master/src/lib.rs), it doesn't look like they load more than 4 bytes at a time.

Your code will look the same as it did before Rust removed `Read::chars`:

```
use std::io::stdin;
use utf8_chars::BufReadCharsExt;

fn main() {
    for c in stdin().lock().chars().map(|x| x.unwrap()) {
        println!("{}", c);
    }
}
```

Add the following to your Cargo.toml:

```
[dependencies]
utf8-chars = "1.0.0"
```

Comment: If there is a common letter, you could read until that character. For example, if you have a line which is 2 GB of A, B, C and D. You could read until an "A"

Answer (score 0):

There are two solutions that make sense here.

First, you could copy the implementation of `Read::chars()` and use it; that would make it completely trivial to move your code over to the standard library implementation if/when it stabilizes.

On the other hand, you could simply iterate line by line (using `f.lines()`) and then use `line.chars()` on each line to get the chars. This is a little more hacky, but it will definitely work.

If you only wanted one loop, you could use `flat_map()` with a lambda like `|line| line.chars()`.

Comment: As a heads-up, it's generally OK to move useful comments to answers, but if you aren't really adding to the content, it's probably [more acceptable to mark the answer as community wiki](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/269913/155423).

Comment: Sorry! I'll make sure to do that next time.