# Why does .flat_map() with .chars() not work with std::io::Lines, but does with a vector of Strings?

Tags: iterator, rust

I am trying to iterate over characters in stdin. The `Read.chars()` method achieves this goal, but is unstable. The obvious alternative is to use `Read.lines()` with a `flat_map` to convert it to a character iterator.

This seems like it should work, but doesn't, resulting in `borrowed value does not live long enough` errors.

```
use std::io::BufRead;

fn main() {
    let stdin = std::io::stdin();
    let mut lines = stdin.lock().lines();
    let mut chars = lines.flat_map(|x| x.unwrap().chars());
}
```

This is mentioned in [Read file character-by-character in Rust](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35385703/read-file-character-by-character-in-rust/37189758), but it does't really explain why.

What I am particularly confused about is how this differs from the example in the [documentation for `flat_map`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.flat_map), which uses `flat_map` to apply `.chars()` to a vector of strings. I don't really see how that should be any different. The main difference I see is that my code needs to call `unwrap()` as well, but changing the last line to the following does not work either:

```
let mut chars = lines.map(|x| x.unwrap());
let mut chars = chars.flat_map(|x| x.chars());
```

It fails on the second line, so the issue doesn't appear to be the `unwrap`.

Why does this last line not work, when the very similar line in the documentation doesn't? Is there any way to get this to work?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Start by figuring out what the type of the closure's variable is:

```
let mut chars = lines.flat_map(|x| {
    let () = x;
    x.unwrap().chars()
});
```

This shows it's a `Result<String, io::Error>`. After `unwrap`ping it, it will be a `String`.

Next, look at [`str::chars`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.str.html#method.chars):

```
fn chars(&self) -> Chars
```

And the [definition of `Chars`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/str/struct.Chars.html):

```
pub struct Chars<'a> {
    // some fields omitted
}
```

From that, we can tell that calling `chars` on a string returns an iterator that has a *reference* to the string.

Whenever we have a reference, we know that the reference cannot outlive the thing that it is borrowed from. In this case, `x.unwrap()` is the owner. The next thing to check is where that ownership *ends*. In this case, the closure owns the `String`, so at the end of the closure, the value is dropped and any references are invalidated.

Except the code tried to return a `Chars` that still referred to the string. Oops. Thanks to Rust, the code didn't segfault!

The difference with the example that works is all in the ownership. In that case, the strings are owned by a vector outside of the loop and they do not get dropped before the iterator is consumed. Thus there are no lifetime issues.

What this code really wants is an `into_chars` method on `String`. That iterator could take ownership of the value and return characters.

---

Not the maximum efficiency, but a good start:

```
struct IntoChars {
    s: String,
    offset: usize,
}

impl IntoChars {
    fn new(s: String) -> Self {
        IntoChars { s: s, offset: 0 }
    }
}

impl Iterator for IntoChars {
    type Item = char;

    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<Self::Item> {
        let remaining = &self.s[self.offset..];

        match remaining.chars().next() {
            Some(c) => {
                self.offset += c.len_utf8();
                Some(c)
            }
            None => None,
        }
    }
}

use std::io::BufRead;

fn main() {
    let stdin = std::io::stdin();
    let lines = stdin.lock().lines();
    let chars = lines.flat_map(|x| IntoChars::new(x.unwrap()));

    for c in chars {
        println!("{}", c);
    }
}
```

See also:

- [How can I store a Chars iterator in the same struct as the String it is iterating on?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43952104/155423)
- [Is there an owned version of String::chars?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47193584/155423)

Comment: Ah, I see, thanks! I suppose what I was confused by is the fact that the functions all deal with `String` rather than `&str`, so it seems like it should be moving the values. But that is not the case since the closures aren't returning the actual values, but rather iterators that are later lazily evaluated, and those iterators contain references to the original object.

Comment: @IanD.Scott While `chars` can be called on a `String`, note that it takes `&self` (a reference) and that it's actually implemented via `Deref`, meaning that the implementation is actually on `str`. Thus `&self` => `&str`.

Comment: Thank you for the `let () = x;` trick for determining the variable type!

Comment: @SlavaSemushin [How do I print the type of a variable in Rust?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/21747136/155423).