# Why can I return an owned value which uses 'char.to_ascii_lowercase()` but not with `str.to_lowercase()`

Tags: rust, lifetime, borrow-checker

Within a function which takes in `&str` and returns `impl Iterator<Item = char>`, I am trying to convert the input to lowercase and then filter and map the characters of that lowered form.  I have been stuck for some time with the following error while using `str.to_lowercase()`:

```
  --> src/lib.rs                                                                                                                      
   |                                                                                                                                        
   |        cipher                                                                                                                          
   |   _____^                                                                                                                               
   |  |_____|                                                                                                                               
   | ||                                                                                                                                     
   | ||         .to_lowercase()                                                                                                             
   | ||_______________________- temporary value created here                                                                                
   | |          .chars()                                                                                                                    
   | |          .filter(|c| c.is_alphanumeric() && c.is_ascii())                                                                            
...  |                                                                                                                                      
   | |              }                                                                                                                       
   | |          })                                                                                                                          
   | |___________^ returns a value referencing data owned by the current function
```

The function in its original form:

```
pub fn decode_to_iter(cipher: &str) -> impl Iterator<Item = char> {
    cipher
        .to_lowercase()
        .chars()
        .filter(|c| c.is_alphanumeric() && c.is_ascii())
        .map(|c| {
            if c.is_alphabetic() {
                (((b'z' - (c as u8)) + b'a') as char)
            } else {
                c
            }
        })
}
```

I came across a couple of questions online asking very similar questions about how to return an owned value that's been transformed with `.to_lowercase()` but none of the solutions posted work for me.

I am trying to avoid using `&char` and stick with `char` in my return type.

I've tried to use functions like `.to_owned()` to take ownership of the reference but have come up empty-handed.

Ultimately, I was able to get my function to compile and pass my tests using `char.to_ascii_lowercase()`.  The working version of my function is:

```
pub fn decode_to_iter<'a>(cipher: &'a str) -> impl Iterator<Item = char> + 'a {
    cipher
        .chars()
        .filter(|c| c.is_alphanumeric() && c.is_ascii())
        .map(|c| {
            if c.is_alphabetic() {
                (((b'z' - (c.to_ascii_lowercase() as u8)) + b'a') as char)
            } else {
                c.to_ascii_lowercase()
            }
        })
}
```

One of the things that are confusing me the most is what the difference between the `str.to_lowercase()` and `char.to_ascii_lowercase()` is.  The documentation for `.to_ascii_lowercase()` under [Primative Type Char](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.char.html#method.to_ascii_lowercase) shows:

```
pub fn to_ascii_lowercase(&self) -> char
```

while the documentation for `.to_lowercase()` under [Primative Type Str](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.str.html) shows:

```
pub fn to_lowercase(&self) -> String
```

Unless I'm misunderstanding, both functions seem to return an owned value so I am unsure why only `char.to_ascii_lowercase()` works.

I am wondering:

1. how to properly return an `Impl Iterator` value which uses `.to_lowercase()` rather than `.to_ascsii_lowercase()`?
2. what the difference is between `char.to_lowercase()` and `str.to_ascii_lowercase()`?

Comment: That's because [`chars()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.str.html#method.chars) borrows the string.

Comment: Does your string contain only ASCII chars?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue here is that [`str::to_lowercase`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.str.html#method.to_lowercase) allocates a new `String` value as the lowercased version of your string, and *then* the [`str::chars`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.str.html#method.chars) method borrows from that new `String` value. (You can tell it borrows from the `String` value by looking at the [`std::str::Chars`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/str/struct.Chars.html) struct, which has a lifetime parameter referring to the string whose characters it is iterating over.)

So why is this problematic? Well, that `String` value allocated by `to_lowercase` is a temporary value created as part of your iterator chain, which is in turn dropped at the end of your function's scope (the compiler's error message should tell you this). Therefore, the compiler is preventing you from a use-after-free bug. If it let you return the iterator, then it would allow callers to read from a `String` that had been deallocated, which violates memory safety.

Your variant that uses `char::to_ascii_lowercase` works because you never allocate that intermediate `String` value. Therefore, you wind up returning an iterator that borrows from the input to the function, which is valid, and is why you needed to add a lifetime parameter. (Otherwise, the compiler assumes the lifetime on a `impl Trait` is `'static`, which is not the case here. The lifetime of your returned value is *tied* to the lifetime of the input to the function.)

You can fix this by avoiding the allocation of a temporary `String`, which should hopefully be more efficient. The trick is to realize that `char` has a method [`char::to_lowercase`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.char.html#method.to_lowercase) which returns an *iterator* over the lowercase equivalent of the given character, and *not* a `String`. Therefore, you can just read from this directly:

```rust
pub fn decode_to_iter<'a>(cipher: &'a str) -> impl Iterator<Item = char> + 'a {
    cipher
        .chars()
        .flat_map(|c| c.to_lowercase())
        .filter(|c| c.is_alphanumeric() && c.is_ascii())
        .map(|c| {
            if c.is_alphabetic() {
                (((b'z' - (c as u8)) + b'a') as char)
            } else {
                c
            }
        })
}
```

The only real trick here is to use `flat_map`, which is like a normal `map`, but it lets you return an iterator that is then flattened into the original iterator (if you used a normal `map` here, you'd wind up with an iterator of iterators).

With that said, if you really only care about ASCII codepoints here (due to your `filter` predicate), then you don't need the full Unicode aware lowercasing mechanism. So I'd probably write it similarly to your second variant, with `char::to_ascii_lowercase`:

```rust
pub fn decode_to_iter<'a>(cipher: &'a str) -> impl Iterator<Item = char> + 'a {
    cipher
        .chars()
        .filter(|c| c.is_ascii_alphanumeric())
        .map(|c| c.to_ascii_lowercase())
        .map(|c| {
            if c.is_alphabetic() {
                (((b'z' - (c as u8)) + b'a') as char)
            } else {
                c
            }
        })
}
```

And here's a [playground link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=7b27ba2f118dd39c627c913a99117fd4) showing the code.

Comment: Thanks @BurntSushi5 for the explanation and for pointing out the use of `flat_map`.  You make a good point about avoiding an unnecessary String allocation by using `char` lowercase methods but I'm still wondering if it is possible to take ownership of the temporary string from `str::to_lowercase` within the iterator chain to avoid having it dropped at the end of the function scope?

Comment: @AC-5 That would be answered by [How can I store a Chars iterator in the same struct as the String it is iterating on?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43952104/3650362)