# Creating an owned iterator with lines

Tags: rust, ownership

I am learning Rust by following the Rust Book and I am currently trying to modify the project in Chapter 12, but I can't understand why my code is not working.

The function in question is the `search` function

```
fn search(query: &str, contents: String) -> Vec<String> {
    contents.lines().filter(|line| line.contains(query)).collect()
}
```

which is supposed to get contents of a file as a string and return a collection of the lines in the file containing `query`. In this form, it throws the error "a value of type `std::vec::Vec<std::string::String>` cannot be built from an iterator over elements of type `&str`".

I think that the error comes from the use of `lines` since it doesn't take ownership of `contents`. My question is if there is a better way to do this or if there is a similar method to `lines` that does take ownership.

Comment: Add `.map (String::from)` before the `.collect()`: [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=303e4a9535db35686d19052de8e90be1)

Comment: If you actually want to return an iterator owning `content`, you can also use the techniques described in [Is there an owned version of String::chars?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47193584/is-there-an-owned-version-of-stringchars) and [How can I store a Chars iterator in the same struct as the String it is iterating on?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43952104/how-can-i-store-a-chars-iterator-in-the-same-struct-as-the-string-it-is-iteratin)

Comment: "My question is if there is a better way to do this or if there is a similar method to lines that does take ownership." there is not because it doesn't really make sense: usually the point of taking ownership is to be more efficient e.g. by reusing an existing allocation. But with an unspecified allocator you can't generically "split" a big allocation into lots of small ones, so there is no way for Rust to generically reuse `contents`' buffer for the `lines`. Therefore there's no point to an owning iterator, you can just `map` to a `str->String` conversion as Jmb shows.

Comment: "Therefore there's no point to an owning iterator" (except for borrinwing-related issues)

Answer (score 3):

As a Rust learner it is important to know the differences between strings (String) and string slices (&str), and how those two types interact.

The [lines() method of an &str](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.str.html#method.lines) returns the lines as iterator over &str, which is the same type.
However the [lines method of a string](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/string/struct.String.html#method.lines) also returns an iterator over &str, which is the same type as before but in this case not the same type as the input.
This means, your output will be of type Vec<&str>.
However in that case you need a *lifetime* because otherwise you can't return a reference. In this case your example would look like this:

```
fn search<'a>(query: &str, contents: &'a str) -> Vec<&'a str> { 
    contents.lines().filter(|line| line.contains(query)).collect()
}

fn main() {
 println!("found: {:?}",search("foo", "the foot\nof the\nfool"));    
}
```

However if you want the vector to contain strings, you can use the `to_owned()` function to convert a &str into a String:

```rust
fn search(query: &str, contents: &str) -> Vec<String> {         
    contents.lines().map(|line| line.to_owned()).filter(|line| line.contains(query)).collect()
}

fn main() {
 println!("{:?}",search("foo", "the foot\nof the\nfool")); 
}
```

However this is inefficient because some strings are created that aren't used so it is better to map last:

```rust
fn search(query: &str, contents: &str) -> Vec<String> {         
    contents.lines().filter(|line| line.contains(query)).map(|line| line.to_owned()).collect()
}

fn main() {
 println!("{:?}",search("foo", "the foot\nof the\nfool")); 
}
```

Or with `contents` of type String, but I think this doesn't make much sense:

```rust
fn search(query: &str, contents: String) -> Vec<String> {       
    contents.lines().map(|line| line.to_owned()).filter(|line| line.contains(query)).collect()
}

fn main() {
 println!("{:?}",search("foo", "the foot\nof the\nfool".to_owned()));
}
```

Explanation: Passing `contents` as a `String` isn't very useful because the search function will own it, but it is not mutable, so you can't change it to the search result, and also your search result is a vector, and you can't transform a single owned String into multiple owned ones.

P.S.: I'm also relatively new to Rust, so feel free to comment or edit my post if I missed something.