# Is there an owned version of String::chars?

Tags: string, iterator, rust, ownership

The following code does not compile:

```
use std::str::Chars;

struct Chunks {
    remaining: Chars,
}

impl Chunks {
    fn new(s: String) -> Self {
        Chunks {
            remaining: s.chars(),
        }
    }
}
```

The error is:

```
error[E0106]: missing lifetime specifier
 --> src/main.rs:4:16
  |
4 |     remaining: Chars,
  |                ^^^^^ expected lifetime parameter
```

`Chars` doesn't own the characters it iterates over and it can't outlive the `&str` or `String` it was created from.

Is there an owned version of `Chars` that does not need a lifetime parameter or do I have to keep a `Vec<char>` and an index myself?

Comment: As an aside: it's likely good to make `Chunks` generic over the iterator type: `struct Chunks<Iter> {...}`, `impl<Iter: Iterator<Item = char>> Chunks<Iter> {..}`, `fn new<IntoIter: IntoIterator<Item = char>>(iter: IntoIter) ->Self {...}`. Then it doesn't care at all about where the chars come from; it could be owned, borrowed, whatever.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`std::vec::IntoIter` is an owned version of every iterator, in a sense.

```
use std::vec::IntoIter;

struct Chunks {
    remaining: IntoIter<char>,
}

impl Chunks {
    fn new(s: String) -> Self {
        Chunks {
            remaining: s.chars().collect::<Vec<_>>().into_iter(),
        }
    }
}
```

[Playground link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=74be704c5cc0f81bcc27c41c51576a61&version=stable)

Downside is additional allocation and a space overhead, but I am not aware of the iterator for your specific case.

Answer (score 7):

There's also the [owned-chars crate](https://github.com/durka/owned-chars), which

> provides an extension trait for String with two methods, into_chars and into_char_indices. These methods parallel String::chars and String::char_indices, but the iterators they create consume the String instead of borrowing it.

Answer (score 5):

## Ouroboros

You can use the [ouroboros](https://crates.io/crates/ouroboros) crate to create a self-referential struct containing the `String` and a `Chars` iterator:

```rust
use ouroboros::self_referencing; // 0.4.1
use std::str::Chars;

#[self_referencing]
pub struct IntoChars {
    string: String,
    #[borrows(string)]
    chars: Chars<'this>,
}

// All these implementations are based on what `Chars` implements itself

impl Iterator for IntoChars {
    type Item = char;

    #[inline]
    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<Self::Item> {
        self.with_mut(|me| me.chars.next())
    }

    #[inline]
    fn count(mut self) -> usize {
        self.with_mut(|me| me.chars.count())
    }

    #[inline]
    fn size_hint(&self) -> (usize, Option<usize>) {
        self.with(|me| me.chars.size_hint())
    }

    #[inline]
    fn last(mut self) -> Option<Self::Item> {
        self.with_mut(|me| me.chars.last())
    }
}

impl DoubleEndedIterator for IntoChars {
    #[inline]
    fn next_back(&mut self) -> Option<Self::Item> {
        self.with_mut(|me| me.chars.next_back())
    }
}

impl std::iter::FusedIterator for IntoChars {}

// And an extension trait for convenience

trait IntoCharsExt {
    fn into_chars(self) -> IntoChars;
}

impl IntoCharsExt for String {
    fn into_chars(self) -> IntoChars {
        IntoCharsBuilder {
            string: self,
            chars_builder: |s| s.chars(),
        }
        .build()
    }
}
```

See also:

- [How can I store a Chars iterator in the same struct as the String it is iterating on?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43952104/155423)

## Rental

You can use the [rental](https://crates.io/crates/rental) crate to create a self-referential struct containing the `String` and a `Chars` iterator:

```rust
#[macro_use]
extern crate rental;

rental! {
    mod into_chars {
        pub use std::str::Chars;

        #[rental]
        pub struct IntoChars {
            string: String,
            chars: Chars<'string>,
        }
    }
}

use into_chars::IntoChars;

// All these implementations are based on what `Chars` implements itself

impl Iterator for IntoChars {
    type Item = char;

    #[inline]
    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<Self::Item> {
        self.rent_mut(|chars| chars.next())
    }

    #[inline]
    fn count(mut self) -> usize {
        self.rent_mut(|chars| chars.count())
    }

    #[inline]
    fn size_hint(&self) -> (usize, Option<usize>) {
        self.rent(|chars| chars.size_hint())
    }

    #[inline]
    fn last(mut self) -> Option<Self::Item> {
        self.rent_mut(|chars| chars.last())
    }
}

impl DoubleEndedIterator for IntoChars {
    #[inline]
    fn next_back(&mut self) -> Option<Self::Item> {
        self.rent_mut(|chars| chars.next_back())
    }
}

impl std::iter::FusedIterator for IntoChars {}

// And an extension trait for convenience 

trait IntoCharsExt {
    fn into_chars(self) -> IntoChars;
}

impl IntoCharsExt for String {
    fn into_chars(self) -> IntoChars {
        IntoChars::new(self, |s| s.chars())
    }
}
```

See also:

- [How can I store a Chars iterator in the same struct as the String it is iterating on?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43952104/155423)

Answer (score 3):

Here is a solution without `unsafe`.

It provides the same effect as `s.chars().collect::<Vec<_>>().into_iter()`, but without the allocation overhead.

Further, it probably as fast as it's possible to get it. It doesn't reallocate, doesn't iterate repeatedly, it simply steps from character to character, in `O(1)` for every step, giving you a total iteration of `O(n)`. This is at the same time the lower bound of iterating over anything.

On top of it it isn't self-referential. So this approach is probably what you want, it combines all the advantages of the other answers and doesn't have any drawbacks.

```rust
struct OwnedChars {
    s: String,
    index: usize,
}

impl OwnedChars {
    pub fn new(s: String) -> Self {
        Self { s, index: 0 }
    }
}

impl Iterator for OwnedChars {
    type Item = char;

    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<Self::Item> {
        // Slice of leftover characters
        let slice = &self.s[self.index..];

        // Iterator over leftover characters
        let mut chars = slice.chars();

        // Query the next char
        let next_char = chars.next()?;

        // Compute the new index by looking at how many bytes are left
        // after querying the next char
        self.index = self.s.len() - chars.as_str().len();

        // Return next char
        Some(next_char)
    }
}
```

Together with a little bit of trait magic:

```rust
trait StringExt {
    fn into_chars(self) -> OwnedChars;
}
impl StringExt for String {
    fn into_chars(self) -> OwnedChars {
        OwnedChars::new(self)
    }
}
```

You can do:

```rust
struct Chunks {
    remaining: OwnedChars,
}

impl Chunks {
    fn new(s: String) -> Self {
        Chunks {
            remaining: s.into_chars(),
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I suppose `s.chars().collect::<Vec<_>>().into_iter()` does not allocate since it is a special case that is handled by the standard library?

Comment: @StephenChung I'm not sure. I had the impression that it does allocate. What's the reason you believe it doesn't?

Answer (score 1):

As copied from [How can I store a Chars iterator in the same struct as the String it is iterating on?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43952104/155423):

```
use std::mem;
use std::str::Chars;

/// I believe this struct to be safe because the String is
/// heap-allocated (stable address) and will never be modified
/// (stable address). `chars` will not outlive the struct, so
/// lying about the lifetime should be fine.
///
/// TODO: What about during destruction?
///       `Chars` shouldn't have a destructor...
struct OwningChars {
    _s: String,
    chars: Chars<'static>,
}

impl OwningChars {
    fn new(s: String) -> Self {
        let chars = unsafe { mem::transmute(s.chars()) };
        OwningChars { _s: s, chars }
    }
}

impl Iterator for OwningChars {
    type Item = char;
    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<Self::Item> {
        self.chars.next()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could implement your own iterator, or wrap `Chars` like this (with just one small `unsafe` block):

```
// deriving Clone would be buggy. With Rc<>/Arc<> instead of Box<> it would work though.
struct OwnedChars {
    // struct fields are dropped in order they are declared,
    // see https://stackoverflow.com/a/41056727/1478356
    // with `Chars` it probably doesn't matter, but for good style `inner`
    // should be dropped before `storage`.

    // 'static lifetime must not "escape" lifetime of the struct
    inner: ::std::str::Chars<'static>,
    // we need to box anyway to be sure the inner reference doesn't move when
    // moving the storage, so we can erase the type as well.
    // struct OwnedChar<S: AsRef<str>> { ..., storage: Box<S> } should work too
    storage: Box<AsRef<str>>,
}

impl OwnedChars {
    pub fn new<S: AsRef<str>+'static>(s: S) -> Self {
        let storage = Box::new(s) as Box<AsRef<str>>;
        let raw_ptr : *const str = storage.as_ref().as_ref();
        let ptr : &'static str = unsafe { &*raw_ptr };
        OwnedChars{
            storage: storage,
            inner: ptr.chars(),
        }
    }

    pub fn as_str(&self) -> &str {
        self.inner.as_str()
    }
}

impl Iterator for OwnedChars {
    // just `char` of course
    type Item = <::std::str::Chars<'static> as Iterator>::Item;

    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<Self::Item> {
        self.inner.next()
    }
}

impl DoubleEndedIterator for OwnedChars {
    fn next_back(&mut self) -> Option<Self::Item> {
        self.inner.next_back()
    }
}

impl Clone for OwnedChars {
    fn clone(&self) -> Self {
        // need a new allocation anyway, so simply go for String, and just
        // clone the remaining string
        OwnedChars::new(String::from(self.inner.as_str()))
    }
}

impl ::std::fmt::Debug for OwnedChars {
    fn fmt(&self, f: &mut ::std::fmt::Formatter) -> ::std::fmt::Result {
        let storage : &str = self.storage.as_ref().as_ref();
        f.debug_struct("OwnedChars")
            .field("storage", &storage)
            .field("inner", &self.inner)
            .finish()
    }
}

// easy access
trait StringExt {
    fn owned_chars(self) -> OwnedChars;
}
impl<S: AsRef<str>+'static> StringExt for S {
    fn owned_chars(self) -> OwnedChars {
        OwnedChars::new(self)
    }
}
```

See [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=dc0ea470357b79d740e982c7c8b78e2a&version=stable)

Comment: [The same thing](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=8a5cc326c0fa08cafe7733251ac53546&version=stable), but using [rental crate](https://crates.io/crates/rental). Unfortunately, it doesn't work in playground.

Comment: Why is the extra box necessary? `S` can only be `String`, `Box<str>` or some other kind of owning `str` reference, right? So the storage must be heap allocated (if it's not `'static`) and therefore won't move until the `S` is dropped. (As long as `OwnedChars` doesn't `push` things on or otherwise trigger a move.)

Comment: I could create a string storage type with small-string optimization (see [`smallvec`](https://crates.io/crates/smallvec) create).

Comment: @Stefan Ah, true. But it seems like the normal use for this struct is when you have a `String` in hand and in that case it's double boxed. Do you think it would be safe to store a `Box<str>` instead and have `new<S: Into<Box<str>>>`? That would work for any reference as well as owned `String`s, only copies the contents when necessary, and doesn't double-box.

Comment: I'm not sure about the allocation overhead of converting `String` to `Box<str>` - if it reuses the `Vec` memory this should be faster, yes. If you know you only want to do this for `String`s you can just use that (unboxed) instead too of course - afaict `String` guarantees heap allocation.