# How to iterate over the chars in a file

Tags: file, iterator, rust

Related: [Read file character-by-character in Rust](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35385703/read-file-character-by-character-in-rust), but the answers there do not address the question of how to produce an `Iterator` that yields the characters in a file.

I am writing a function with a signature like this:

```
fn lex(chars: Iterator<Item=char>) -> Tokens {
}
```

that takes in an iterator of `char`s, and returns another iterator.

I want to be able to write tests for this function, e.g. by passing in the result of calling `chars()` on a string object.

In my product, on the code, I want to read a text file and pass the characters in that file in to my function.  For the moment, I don't care what happens if the file is not valid UTF-8.

I would be happy to change the signature of the function, e.g. to take in an `Iterator<Item=Result<char, SomeErrorType>>`, but I do want to consume the file on demand, not read the whole thing in beforehand.

I would be happy to use a `BufRead` and an `io::Cursor` in test if that helped.

I looked at calling `chars()` on a [`Read`](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/27802) but it is unstable and looks like it will never become stable.

So, how do I iterate over the characters in a file?